# Recognize which control touched

Tags: xcode, ios4, iphone

Imagine that i put several controls on view how can i recognize which control touched ?

I use below code but doesn't work

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if([touch view]==btn)
       //...
}
```

Comment: why don't use IBActions / UIControl-Events ?

Comment: Becuase i have many controls and just want to drag them

Comment: it would be better not to use UIControl objects (read UIButton) if you want to drag them around.... better use UIImageViews...

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Instantiate one and hook it to each view you want to have be draggable. Then when it fires, use its `translationInView:` method to get the translation to apply to the view itself.

See here for the docs on UIPanGestureRecognizer: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer